# npm adduser Incorrect username or password

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, npm-request

I am newbie to npm. I am trying to create username password with npm.

Here is my code:

```
abhi@abhi-Lenovo-Z50-70:~/Desktop/CSS_HTML/With_JS$ npm adduser

Username: abhishek
Password: 
Email: (this IS public) parikh5555@gmail.com
```

> npm WARN adduser Incorrect username or password
>   npm WARN adduser You can reset your account by visiting: npm WARN adduser
>   npm WARN adduser https://npmjs.org/forgot npm WARN adduser
>   npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
>   npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "adduser"
>   npm ERR! node v6.3.1
>   npm ERR! npm v3.10.3 npm ERR! code E401
>   npm ERR! Registry returned 401 for PUT on
>   http://registry.npmjs.org/-/user/org.couchdb.user:abhishek

Comment: It was happening to me after enabling 2FA. Disabled 2FA and it started working again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have registered on https://www.npmjs.com/ and are sure that your username and password is correct, delete `$HOME/.npmrc` and try `adduser` again.

This may be caused by a bug recorded here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6545

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the right username you have probably forgotten your password. From the docs you should [use this link to reset](https://www.npmjs.com/forgot).

The full documentation can be found [by following this link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/adduser) where you can also register.

Comment: hey @alexi2 Thanks for reply.. Is this means I have to register my self first on npm and then I can add user in my registry? Adduser user will require this?

Answer (score 1):

We have to Register on https://www.npmjs.com/ for adding new user